# Using Javascript and Facebook Graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to publish to another user wall, so it would appear as if HE published this post himself. For example, I want to write "I've published a new article on Youngo.com" on his wall.

I have an offline access and stream publish permissions. I also got the access token. I just can't figure how to do that using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
var wallPost = {
    access_token: "<ACCESS_TOKEN>",
    message: 'Hello, World!'
};

FB.api('/<UID>/feed', 'post', wallPost, function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occurred');
    } else {
        alert('Success!');
    }
});
```

Comment: @Omri what error are you getting exactly? dump the response into firebug console.

Comment: When the token is mine and the UID is "me" - That works.
But if I change the token and the UID to another user, it alerts me with an error. What can I use to see the full error details?

Comment: @Omri well if you don't have firebug then at least do `alert(response.error);`, if you do have firebug then `console.log(response);`

Comment: It just says:   object Object

Comment: @Omri it returns some error code inside that object, you need to read it somehow. If you don't know a better way then go grab firebug, it would save you lot of time. If you have Chrome you can also use `console.log` to explore all fields of an object.

Comment: I think i figured the problem out...Something was wrong with the permissions...Does someone knows how to check and ask for permissions using JavaScript?

Comment: Thanks a lot!

And I also didn't find a way to delete posts from another user wall. The examples on the Facebook Developers area doesn't show that...

Can someone please help?

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to post to FB's API directly from javascript it won't work.  You have to wrap their api with a web service on your domain since javascript isn't allowed to do cross domain requests.

Comment: I can publish to my own stream or make my website publish to the current user's session (as long as he has given the right permissions...) so why can't I publish on the other user's behalf If I have his access token?

Comment: JSON-P enables cross domain requests everywhere. Modern browsers (IE8+, FF3, Chrome, Safari) also enable this natively. Flash also helps.

Comment: I don't think JSONP is needed when the JavaScript is loaded from the same domain to which the external calls are made too (by that JavaScript).